# Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm making a C# class library, for .NET 6, that does a bunch of setup for web configuration and HTTP.  On the `IServiceCollection` I'm trying to call the `Configure` method that takes a section, like so:

```cs
IServiceCollection services = ...
IConfigurationSection section = ...


services.Configure<MySettings>(section);
```

If I do that right in a web project it works great.  In the class library project, the extension method that takes an `IConfigurationSection` doesn't exist.

In the web project it seems like this comes from Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, but it must be somewhere else. For the library project, I included the following NuGet packages.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="5.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.15.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Not an answer but TBH mixing "different" versions of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http...` looks a little bit suspicious to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing [Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/) package.

Also note that [`OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#overloads) overloads accept `IConfiguration` interface, which is base for `IConfigurationSection`.